# Python: Is this a problem in my console settings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, console, output

I started learning python and now I stuck with this "easy" code. Where is the problem, thanks in advance!

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
age = input("Enter your age: ")
print("Hello " + name + "! Your are " + age)
```

...in the console the strings (name + input) are red and while I´m typing, I can´t see what I´m typing. After I entered a name and press enter, I get this in my console:

```
Enter your name:Hello Bob! Your are
 Enter your age:
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Works fine on my end. What console are you using?

Comment: for me your code works fine

Comment: Your console is probably writing the output into the input. Try IPython.

Comment: @glhr I´m using Pycharm

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the Run configuration in PyCharm. Try copying your code to a new project, and run it from there.

Comment: @glhr yeah thank you, now it´s working. So should I delete this project, an copie all files in a new project?

Comment: That would be the easiest way. Or try to edit/reset the Run configuration in your current project.

Comment: @glhr Okay, I just copied all my files now in a new project, thank you